# Advanced Form creation - needed advice or suggestion

Tags: forms, ms-access-2016, subform

I have a dataset in MsAccess:

Fact Table - **ChartReview**:

```
    ID  EmployeeFK  CategoryFK  ObjectiveFK YesNoFK
     1          22           1            1       0
     2          11           1            2       1
     3          11           2            3       1
     4          22           3            6       2
     5          22           2            5       0
     6          22           2            4       1
```

Dimension Tables -

**3_Employee**:

```
     ID EmployeeName

     11 James Smith
     22 John Doe
```

**4_YesNo**:

```
     ID DescriptionYesNo

     0  N/A
     1  Yes
     2  No
```

**1_Category**:

```
    ID  DescriptionCategory

    1   Orientation
    2   Individual
    3   Progress
```

**2_Objective**:

```
   ID   CategoryFK  DescriptionObjective

    1   1           Object1
    2   1           Object2
    3   2           Object345
    4   2           Object556
    5   2           Object666
    6   3           ObjectLast
```

Here is the Relations Model (colored dots show the appropriate relation):

[image]

My goal is to create a Form or (Form + SubForm)- where user will add data as following -

User will select the **EmployeeName**, and then - will proceed with the **Category** selection.

Then - will enter the **Objective** values (**Yes**, **No** or **N/A**) according to each **Category** associated with its **Objective**.

I created the Main Form (data source - **ChartReview** table):
[image]

and the Sub Form (data source - dimensions - **Category**, **Objective** tables):
[image]

But - my problem - I don't know how to connect **MainForm + SubForm**...

(so the user would enter data into **Main**, and then would be transferred to a **Sub** and will enter **Yes**/**No**/**N/A** for each **Objective**)

Also, I need my **Yes**/**No**/**N/A** values would be bound to **each** Objective, while now, unfortunately they're bound to only the 1st Objective...

And the last, I am not even sure the user will actually be able to fill out my **SubForm**, as it's created out of the Dimensions.
When I tried to enter or to change the info in the **SubForm** - the following error appears:
[image]

Any advice or suggestions - welcome !!!

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view.
Click on the subform to select it.
If you can't see the properties pane, Right click on the subform and choose properties.
On the data tab there are the fields that you need to fill in.
Link Master Fields and Link Child Fields.

To start, put 3_Employee.ID in the "link Master fields" box
and ChartReview.EmployeeFK in the "Link Child Fields" box.
Manually enter valid data to test that the employee record works, then add the other links once this works.